# Making a weekly calendar to reflect days of week with correct dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

[weekly calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb6RW.png)<----img here--!
I have a weekly table that i want to integrate a calendar system to it. in the img where it shows the year, i would like to have it show a 7day week (example: 12/20/20 - 12/27/2020), with the dates directly reflecting the days of the week. id also like to add buttons to go to prev and next week with the days of the week also rolling over to correspond to that week. i can take care of the data that will go in the cells under the days and update those when i have this calendar rolling. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Do want to do this without the help of a library?

Comment: Please show what research you've done and what attempts you've made into solving this issue yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example I made using HTML, CSS, and JS.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="calendar">
    <div class="nav">
      <i id="prev" class="fas fa-arrow-left arrow" tabindex="0"></i>
      <div class="calendar-icon-container">
        <h1 id="date-range"></h1>
        <div>
          <div id="calendar-popover" class="calendar-popover hidden">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <i id="next" class="fas fa-arrow-right arrow" tabindex="0"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="header" class="header">
      <div>
        <div>Monday</div>
        <div class="date"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>Tuesday</div>
        <div class="date"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>Wednesday</div>
        <div class="date"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>Thursday</div>
        <div class="date"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>Friday</div>
        <div class="date"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>Saturday</div>
        <div class="date"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>Sunday</div>
        <div class="date"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <div>
          <li>text</li>
      </div>
      <div>
          <li>text</li>
      </div>
      <div>
          <li>text</li>
      </div>
      <div>
          <li>....</li>
      </div>
      <div>
          <li>text</li>
      </div>
      <div>
          <li>text</li>
      </div>
      <div>
          <li>text</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.container {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     flex-direction: column;
}
 .calendar > .nav {
     align-items: center;
}
 .calendar > div {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-evenly;
}
 .calendar > div > div {
     padding: 12px;
}
 .calendar > .header > div, .calendar > .body > div {
     flex: 1 0 120px;
     border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
 .fas:focus {
     outline: none;
     opacity: 1;
}
```

JS code:

```
(function() {
  var mondayRef = 1;
  var sundayRef = 7;
  
  var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
  var next = document.getElementById('next');
  var dateRange = document.getElementById('date-range');
  var dateViews = document.getElementsByClassName('date');
  var daysOfMonth = document.getElementById('days-of-month');
  var calendarPopover = document.getElementById('calendar-popover');
  
 
  function adjustCalendar(monRef, sunRef) {
    var monday = moment().day(monRef);
    var sunday = moment().day(sunRef);
    
    if (monRef > 0) {
      for (var date = monRef; date <= sunRef; date++) {
        dateViews[(date - 1) % 7].innerHTML = moment().day(date).format('M[/]D');
      }
    } else {
      for (var date = -monRef; date >= -sunRef; date --) {
        dateViews[-(monRef + date)].innerHTML = moment().day(-date).format('M[/]D');
      }
    }
  
    if (monday.format('YYYY') !== sunday.format('YYYY')) {
      dateRange.innerHTML = `${monday.format('MMMM Do, YYYY')} - ${sunday.format('MMMM Do, YYYY')}`;
    } else {
      dateRange.innerHTML = `${monday.format('MMMM Do')} - ${sunday.format('MMMM Do, YYYY')}`;
    }
  }
  
  // Init
  adjustCalendar(mondayRef, sundayRef);
  
  next.onclick = function() {
    mondayRef += 7;
    sundayRef += 7;
    adjustCalendar(mondayRef, sundayRef);
  }
  
  prev.onclick = function() {
    mondayRef -= 7;
    sundayRef -= 7;
    adjustCalendar(mondayRef, sundayRef);
  }
})();
```

If you want it to look nicer and add on to it, you are welcome to do so. I advise you to use the table approach as it will make it easier for you to design the widths, heights, borders, etc. Good luck!